# assertJson() for odered JSON arrays in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, rest, unit-testing

I am recreating a simple api for Laravel from this page:
https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial?utm_campaign=blog_post_restful_laravel_api_tutorial&utm_medium=email&utm_source=blog_subscribers

In the testing phase, I am encoutering problem in `testArticlesAreListedCorrectly()` function in `ArticleTest.php`. The code aren't perfect in the page, like I had to change to `jsonAssert()` to `jsonAssertFragment()` for the testing to work. But asserting multiple Json arrays in a response seems to be difficult, and shows error. Is there a way to use JsonFragment for both arrays while simultaneously checking if they are listed properly?

```
public function testArticlesAreListedCorrectly()
{

    factory(Article::class)->create([
        'title' => 'First Article',
        'body' => 'First Body'
    ]);

    factory(Article::class)->create([
        'title' => 'Second Article',
        'body' => 'Second Body'
    ]);

    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    $token = $user->generateToken();
    $headers = ['Authorization' => "Bearer $token"];

    $response = $this->json('GET','/api/articles', [], $headers)
        ->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJson([
            ['title' => 'First Article', 'body' => 'First Body'],
            ['title' => 'Second Article', 'body' => 'Second Body']
        ])
        ->assertJsonStructure([
            '*' => ['id', 'body', 'title', 'created_at', 'updated_at'],
        ]);
}
```

Error:

````
....F........                                                     13 / 13 (100%)

Time: 23.53 seconds, Memory: 28.00 MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Feature\ArticleTest::testArticlesAreListedCorrectly
Unable to find JSON: 

[[
    {
        "title": "First Article",
        "body": "First Body"
    },
    {
        "title": "Second Article",
        "body": "Second Body"
    }
]]

within response JSON:

[[

        "id": 51,
        "title": "First Article",
        "body": "First Body",
        "created_at": "2019-11-27 06:01:13",
        "updated_at": "2019-11-27 06:01:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 52,
        "title": "Second Article",
        "body": "Second Body",
        "created_at": "2019-11-27 06:01:13",
        "updated_at": "2019-11-27 06:01:13"
    }
]].


Failed asserting that an array has the subset Array &0 (
    0 => Array &1 (
        'title' => 'First Article'
        'body' => 'First Body'
    )
    1 => Array &2 (
        'title' => 'Second Article'
        'body' => 'Second Body'
    )
).
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
   0 => 
   array (
     'id' => 1,
-    'title' => 'First Article',
-    'body' => 'First Body',
+    'title' => 'Modi distinctio officiis similique quis ut suscipit facilis.',
+    'body' => 'Reiciendis iste beatae rerum dolore nesciunt ullam est. Accusamus autem eaque nihil voluptates suscipit incidunt. Et voluptas voluptas non sint.',
     'created_at' => '2019-11-27 06:01:12',
     'updated_at' => '2019-11-27 06:01:12',
   ),
@@ @@
   1 => 
   array (
     'id' => 2,
-    'title' => 'Second Article',
-    'body' => 'Second Body',
+    'title' => 'Suscipit soluta rerum officia voluptatem sint ducimus.',
+    'body' => 'Ut dolor dolorem voluptas sint et alias. Dolores ipsa quasi nisi enim aperiam tenetur. Sed expedita sit impedit at eius quod. Dolore eaque officiis vero consequuntur sit.',
     'created_at' => '2019-11-27 06:01:12',
     'updated_at' => '2019-11-27 06:01:12',
   ),```

Any idea how I can run this test?
````